# How can I coordinate graphic sound waves and Music bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

friends.

[image: image from my program]

I'm making a video editor program.

sound waves and music should be in the same place

I can't align the chart with the Music Bar. I tried set_position but failed. My problem is that the graphic and the music bar do not end in the same place.

Although the wave is over in the chart, the bar still continues with the music.

How can I get these two in line?

```
    self.plt = plt.figure(figsize=(25,2),dpi=35,tight_layout=True,frameon=False,clear=True,constrained_layout=False)
    self.axe = self.plt.add_subplot(111)
    self.axe.yaxis.set_visible(False)
    self.axe.set_position([0.35,0.4,-0.29,0.0])

    self.m2 =  FigureCanvas(self.plt)
    self.m2.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed,QSizePolicy.Fixed)
```

[image: final image]

More descriptive: I want the graphic wave to reach the limit

Comment: Can you change the background of the canvas with timeline to show/reflect a moving graph?

Comment: i think i can change it but it doesn't seem to meet what i want to do.
I want to adjust the forward and rewind operations according to the loudness of the sound by looking at the graph.

Comment: First of all, the margins of the canvas should be aligned with the slider boundaries (or, to be more precise, the *groove* in which the slider handle can move), and you also need to ensure that the shown graph is adapted to the canvas (see `tight_layout()`). You cannot use arbitrary numbers to do any of the above.

Comment: @musicamante I just managed to pull a little to the right by trial and error method.

Comment: @MVX The fact that you had to find the correct position by trial and error demonstrates that it's unreliable. That won't suffice. It *may* work for you in this specific situation, but if the system (or the user) uses a different style or scaling, it will become invalid again. And I strongly believe that it won't work anymore as soon as you resize the window (assuming you properly used layout managers, as you always should).

Comment: @musicamante As far as I understand, I cannot adjust the width of the graphic in the canvas, is this true?